# Is it possible to simulate pressing 'Down' arrow?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I try to figure out how to send <kbd>Down</kbd> in [puppeteer](/questions/tagged/puppeteer), I tried with the int code `40` or `Down` string, but none works.

Is there a proper way ? Can't figure it out after reading `~/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Input.js`

```
const elementHandle = await page.$('selector');
await elementHandle.type('something');
await page.keyboard.press(40); // fail
```

Comment: Can you go into more detail about **how** it doesn't work?  Are you expecting it cause the browser to scroll down?  Typically, manually triggered events don't cause default user agent actions due to security concerns.  I'm not sure if this is the case for puppeteer as well.  What are you expecting to happen.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use `'ArrowDown'`.

The `keyboard.press` functions wants a string as *name* of the key.
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#keyboardpresskey-options

So the line to press the down arrow would be:

```
await page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown');
```

Here is the list of available keys: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/src/common/USKeyboardLayout.ts

Comment: This does not work on a select in MacOS

Comment: @Roel I don't have any way to test that, but I think that would be an issue to create on the [Puppeteer repository](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues).